# Beamer - change transition style within a slide

Tags: beamer, itemize, transition

Preamble

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
```

---

Here is a frame with an itemize list where the items appear one by one. Is it possible to change the transition style between item 2 and item 3?

```
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item item 1 \pause
    \item item 2 with default transition \pause 
    \transdissolve
    \item item 3 with transdissolve transition \pause
    \transreplace
    \item item 4 with default transition \pause
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need to load the packages `amsmath` or `amssymb` in beamer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the desired result of having `item` 3 dissolve, you need to change to

```
\item item 3...
\transdissolve<3>
```

This tells the 3rd frame to dissolve, which doesn't affect the rest.

As karlkoeller points out, you can adjust the duration with the optional argument `[duration = ]` with the time you enter.  Additionally, there is the optional argument `[direction = ]` with the degree you enter.  This affects the effects direction.  See page 141 of the [beamer documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) for more detail.

Comment: What is `\transitiondissolve`?

Comment: @karlkoeller a misspelling

Comment: OK, you can also add to the answer that you can adjust the duration of the effect (e.g. `[duration=0.5]`) so to make it more complete.

Comment: Always use `mirrors.ctan.org` so the user is redirect to the nearest mirror...