# beamer: change the transition style within a frame

Tags: beamer, transition

When running the result of the enclosed MWE (with AR) you will see that the commanded
change in transition style does not take place in time. It will occur only after the 
change of the frame - and this is definitely too late: I like the final result of the
first frame to stay on the display until *I* say 'move on'.

There are some similar questions in stackexchange but they do not deliver a solution as far as I can see. [Even [Beamer - change transition style within a slide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128214/beamer-change-transition-style-within-a-slide) does not work for me, which is really surprising ...] Grateful for every help as always.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\TikZsetword}[2]{\visible<+->{\node at #2 {#1};}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{foo}
\transduration{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \TikZsetword{Rauschleistungsdichte}{(0,0)}
 \TikZsetword{Rauschtemperatur}{(1,1)}
 \TikZsetword{Rauschzahl}{(2,2)}
 \transreplace<3>
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\transreplace
\begin{frame}{bar}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 test
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Document Class: beamer 2015/01/05 3.34 A class for typesetting presentations

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what the issue is here. You've set `\transduration` as 1 second and I get auto-replacement of the slide content when I view in Adobe Reader at full screen (AR 11.0.10.32). What are you seeing? (`\transreplace` is the standard 'flip to the next page' transition.)

Comment: Sorry, yes, what I would like to get is: automagically (\transduration) switching through the first frame, but stopping at the third and last step in this frame (\transreplace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the relationship between `\transduration` and `\transreplace`. The latter is about how a page should change, here a straight swap, ..., but says nothing about how long a page should last for. That is set by `\transduration`. In your example, the `\transduration{1}` applies to all of the first frame, so you get the expected auto-change until you start the second frame. What you therefore need to do is cancel the auto-changing:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\TikZsetword}[2]{\visible<+->{\node at #2 {#1};}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{foo}
\transduration{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \TikZsetword{Rauschleistungsdichte}{(0,0)}
 \TikZsetword{Rauschtemperatur}{(1,1)}
 \TikZsetword{Rauschzahl}{(2,2)}
 \transduration<3>{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{bar}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \TikZsetword{Rauschleistungsdichte}{(0,0)}
 \TikZsetword{Rauschtemperatur}{(1,1)}
 \TikZsetword{Rauschzahl}{(2,2)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Notice that I need to use an empty argument here: setting `\transduration<3>{0}` means 'as fast as possible'!

Comment: You are absolutely right: I did not get the correct meaning of the different \trans...-commands. With `\transduration<+->{}` in my target code I now obtain the required behaviour! Perhaps this section of the fine manual can be optimized? (BTW: all the \trans...-commands did not find the way into the index - beware, this should be no criticism, just a hint!)

Comment: I've added a note to the manual and fixed the lack of indexing of commands (in general!).